# How to check if there is a free spot in an array and then add an object in this spot?

Tags: c, arrays

> I need to check whether there is a free spot in an array and if there
>   is one, then add a pointer to the array in this spot. For example,
>   values[10] so it has 10 elements to get inside, So values[0] and
>   values[1] are taken but the rest is empty, how do I check if that is
>   the case so I can add value in values[2]?

```
    void showAnimals(ANIMAL* values[],int arraySize)
    { 

      for(int i=0;i<= arraySize;i++)
      {
        printf("Age: %d , Name: %s \n",values[i]->Age,values[i]->Name );//, 
        strcpy(name,values[i].Species;));
      }
    }

    void initArray(ANIMAL *values[], int arraySize)
     {
      for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
      {
         values[i] = NULL;
      }
     }

    int addAnimal(ANIMAL animalToAdd, ANIMAL* animalArray[], int arraySize)
    {
        int result = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i <= arraySize; i++)
        {
           if(animalArray[i] == NULL)
           {
             animalArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(ANIMAL));
             animalArray[i]->Age = animalToAdd.Age;
             strcpy(animalArray[i]->Name, animalToAdd.Name);
             animalArray[i]->Species = animalToAdd.Species;
             result = 0;
             return result;
           }
            return result;
       }
     }
```

Comment: You have to define what the free spot means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if an index in a struct array is empty or not in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823984/check-if-an-index-in-a-struct-array-is-empty-or-not-in-c)

Comment: Arrays in C don't have free spots.

Comment: `sizeof(values[i])` will never give `0` as output.

Comment: I mean, for example, values[10] so it has 10 elements to get inside, So values[0] and values[1] are taken but the rest is empty, how do I check if that is the case so I can add value in values[2]?

Comment: You can define the array as an ANIMAL object pointers array and set all with NULL at the begining. Each time you are going to create new one, you would make a new. A free spot would be a NULL position in the array.

Comment: `the rest is empty` - The technical term used is "intederminate", in simple words: you cannot determinate the value. It is not known what is in the rest. The is something, maybe random, maybe not. Unless you initialize it, for example set all elements to zero, or to `-1`, or some other "special" value, there is no way to determine if a value is set or unset. If you want such funcionality, add a member `bool is_empty` to your data and set it to true if your data is "empty"; set it to false if yout data is "not empty". For example you could initialize `values[i].Age` to -1 and that way detect.

Comment: Could you use a zero-length `.Name` to mark an empty place in the array? E.g. `if (values[i].Name[0] == '\0')`.

Comment: I believe the best way to do this is to use linked list instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also declare your animals list as an array of pointers to `animal`s. So in that case the `initArray` function purposed above would look something like:

```cpp
void initArray(animal *values[], int arraySize)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
  {
    values[i] = NULL;
  }
}
```

So now you know that if the element `i` is `NULL`, that spot in the array is empty, and can be populated with your new animal. Note that you will need to allocate memory for each animal when you add it, because `animal *myAnimals[10]` only allocates an array of pointers to `animal`, but no memory is allocated for each animal features.

I don't know how your `animal` feature looks like, but I assume is something like this. You should be able to run this example:

```cpp
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct animal{
  int Age;
  char Name[20];
  int Species;
} animal;

void initArray(animal *values[], int arraySize)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
  {
    values[i] = NULL;
  }
}

int addAnimal(animal animalToAdd, animal* animalArray[], int arraySize)
{
  int result = -1;
  for(int i = 0; i <= arraySize; i++)
  {
    if(animalArray[i] == NULL)
    {
      animalArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(animal));
      animalArray[i]->Age = animalToAdd.Age;
      strcpy(animalArray[i]->Name, animalToAdd.Name);
      animalArray[i]->Species = animalToAdd.Species;
      result = 0;
      // You can also use break here instead
      return result;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

int main(){

  animal *myAnimals[10];
  initArray(myAnimals, 10);

  animal animalToAdd0;
  animalToAdd0.Age = 99;
  strcpy(animalToAdd0.Name, "Animal_0");
  animalToAdd0.Species = 1;

  animal animalToAdd1;
  animalToAdd1.Age = 6;
  strcpy(animalToAdd1.Name, "Animal_1");
  animalToAdd1.Species = 3;

  addAnimal(animalToAdd0, myAnimals, 10);
  addAnimal(animalToAdd1, myAnimals, 10);

  printf("Animal 0 name: %s\n", myAnimals[0]->Name);
  printf("Animal 1 name: %s\n", myAnimals[1]->Name);

  // This will fail with seg fault because there is not animal in there
  // and you are trying to access a NULL
  //printf("Animal 2 name: %s\n", myAnimals[2]->Name);

  return 0;
}
```

Some personal suggestions:

- Try to use more meaningful variable names, `arraySize` instead of `number`, or `animalToAdd` instead of `animalPtr`
- Dereferencing a pointer to a struct to access its elements `(*AnimalPtr).Age` is valid, but I think its more readable to access with `AnimalPtr->Age`
- There are many variable naming convections, but for example, I would name a structure with all caps.
- You should consider in your `addAnimal` function a case where the list is full, in which case you should return `!=0` value.

Maybe now you can try to create a `removeAnimal` function, so you can set the element back to `NULL` and free the memory you allocated before.

Edit1: Modified function `addAnimal`, not the optimal solution though.

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you very much. Greatly appreciated. Also, yes, for the most part, my code was the same + some additional methods. Also, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Only one more question: All of this now works, but then I added an else to the if statement in addAnimal method, where else returns -1. When I did this I can print only one animal on the screen even though I have 3 in the array, why is that?

Comment: Just modified the code returning `-1`. So now if you try to call `addAnimal` more than 10 times, at the 11th it will fail, because the array is full and it wont find any element where is empty (equals to `NULL`)

Comment: Animal 0 name: Go
Animal 1 name: (null) 
Still getting one of the animals only printed, the rest are shown as null although they should be in the array.

Comment: Can you show (edit your original post) how you are populating the animals array? With my code its working fine, I am able to add `n` animals and then print its content afterwards.

Comment: It is modified now.

Comment: Please, make sure you double check your code before posting it. I don't understand why you are doing `strcp` inside `showAnimals`. Also, inside `addAnimal` you are using `return` in every iteration of the `for` loop, move it outside of it. Double check my function. Correct also some syntax errors.

Comment: Ah, my bad. The strcp was commented. The rest I fixed and now it works. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

You shall initialize your Animal array to something you can check whether entry is empty or not (have a sentinel value).
e.g. if you decide Age value of '-1' is an invalid value for your scenario, you shall initialize the array to have 'Age' set to -1, then check for it.

init the array:

```
int initArray(ANIMAL values[],int number)
{
    for(int i=0; i<=number; i++)
         values[i].Age = -1;
}
```

Then check of it:

```
int addAnimal(ANIMAL* AnimalPtr,ANIMAL values[],int number)
{
   for(int i=0; i<=number; i++)
   {
       if(values[i].Age == -1)
       {
          values[i].Age = (*AnimalPtr).Age;
          strcpy(values[i].Name, (*AnimalPtr).Name);
          values[i].Species = (*AnimalPtr).Species;
          return 0;
       }
   }
}
```

Alternatively you can add a flag to Animal saying whether it has value or not.

Another attitude is to have array of pointers instead of array of structs, and simply check whether the pointer is null or not. however, this way you'll need to allocate new memory for the placeholder of new added value to the array.

Comment: Did not help :(

Comment: can you supply a minimal program which shows it does not work?
It shall work!